# Is there any idea for double the size of np array?

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array

Hi I'm looking for some python method which can resize the np ndarray.
For example, when I got 2x2 ndarray looks like this,
[[1,1],[1,1]]

then, I want to upsize this in 4X4 size.(I want the way works on any dimention)

I want the new values to be filled to be obtained from the average of the existing adjacent values.
What can I do? Any Ideas?
※when I reduced np, I used this code which I got from stack overflow. this code can transform 4X4 to 2X2

```
compression_pairs = [(d, c//d) for d, c in zip(new_shape,
                                               ndarray.shape)]
flattened = [l for p in compression_pairs for l in p]
ndarray = ndarray.reshape(flattened)
for i in range(len(new_shape)):
    if operation.lower() == "sum":
        ndarray = ndarray.sum(-1*(i+1))
    elif operation.lower() in ["mean", "average", "avg"]:
        ndarray = ndarray.mean(-1*(i+1))
```

Comment: Have a look at `np.pad` function, you control the size and the values that you pad. If you had your 2x2 array in `arr` for example, you would be doing something like this `np.pad(arr, ((1, 1), (1, 1)), constant_values=np.mean(arr))` to end up with 4x4 matrix with the average value padded

Comment: thanks a lot! I'll try this :)

Comment: It's not clear what you intend to do with a larger or more diverse array.  For this simple case `np.ones((4,4),int)` is enough.  But more generally, I'd make a `np.zeros` of the target size, and then think about how I'd assign values.  The 'middle' would be an obvious sliced assignment.  The edge 'mean' values will be trickier.

Comment: @hpaulj won't the method that I suggested work in this case?